# ReactJS Checkbox If Value In Array

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

How to make checkbox input in reactjs checked if the value included inside an array?
I tried to filter the array inside the checked props but still not working

```
  const [productForm, setProductForm] = useState({
    sizes: ["41", "42", "43"],
  });
```

```
                [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45].map((size, index) => (
                  <div className="col-2" key={index}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <label className="form-check-label">
                          <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" name="sizes" value={size} onChange={e => handleCheckBox(e)} checked={productForm.sizes.includes(size)} />
                          <i className="input-helper"></i>
                          {size}
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is correct but you're looking for a number in an array of strings:

```js
["40", "41", "42"].includes(40) // false

[40, 41, 42].includes("40") // false

[40, 41, 42].includes(Number("40")) // true
```

Comment: ahh i see, its work now after converting the value in array same as value in array like this, thanks...